# js.map files being unnecessarily tracked by php logging script - huh?

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I have a weird problem with my .js.map files being unintentionally logged.

In php files I include a header.php file for, well, my header. In my header I include logUserData.php - in which I get the user ip, account info, and log stuff in the database. Basic intention is to track where our users go (not in Analytics, just for our data uses).

Everything works fine, all traffic is logged - but, the .js.map files are tracked. You probably know these aren't listed anywhere in my source. I don't include my logging script in these files, which would be weird anyway.

I have zero purpose to track these files. I don't ever really care if they're called... I can filter them out with the script but that avoids the problem and doesn't fix it.

I have tried moving the include from the header to the footer basically as a shot in the dark. Totally at a loss. I have put the call before and after these scripts, before the html and after.

These are the scripts that have their associated maps called:

```
<script src="/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
```

And here are the only relevant parts of the logging script in case it helps, the rest is just user account and db stuff:

```
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$CurUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$refer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_F ORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

Does anyone have any clue why this might be? I'm totally at a loss.

EDIT: the map files are NOT in my network activity in dev tools and served as application/javascript

Comment: Does sound odd. Your webserver doesn't route all requests via the PHP engine or something??

Comment: Nope. Nothing weird or fancy/unnecessary like that. Just a basic php/html setup - and if that WAS the case wouldn't every request be tracked? Actually, I don't even think that would happen

Comment: Well you did say "all traffic is logged"...did you mean "all PHP traffic"?

Comment: Is it just .map files which are being tracked as well as .php? Are you sure there's no rule in the server config which associated .map files with the PHP engine

Comment: By all traffic I mean the pages requested by the browser as in index.php is tracked by the logUserData.php script. No other requests are logged by this script. All includes, images, javascripts etc. There are no rules associated with map files. The only things logged in the database when loading index.php (for example) are index.php and for some reason three map files.